# Ruby on Rails 4: how do I silence validation error messages for testing?

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I wrote an integration test for my rails app that tests to see that a user who provides a non-matching confirmation password should not be successfully added to the database. The test I wrote is successful, and thats the good part. The really annoying part is this: the password confirmation is validated using a 2 part validation

```
validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true, if: lambda { |m| m.password.present? }
validates_confirmation_of :password, if: ->{ password.present? }
```

Now because in my test I attempt to create a user with a non matching password confirmation, rails automatically adds the message "Password confirmation doesn't match Password" to `user.errors.full_messages`, where `user` is the user I try (and fail) to create. When I run `rake test:integration` I get the following output to the terminal:

```
DROBRO~> rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 2189

# Running:

Password confirmation doesn't match Password
Password confirmation doesn't match Password
Password confirmation doesn't match Password
.

Finished in 0.805430s, 1.2416 runs/s, 12.4157 assertions/s.

1 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

when I just want it to look like this:

```
DROBRO~> rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 2189

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.805430s, 1.2416 runs/s, 12.4157 assertions/s.

1 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

So I have 2 questions:

1) How can I silence these annoying error messages that print in the middle of my '.'s and 'F's??

2) and why is it printing out the message 3 times when I am only attempting to create this user once?

Thanks for the help

### edit:

Here's some extra code to go along with the above question. I do not explicitly have any `puts` statements anywhere which explicitly print the error messages to the terminal, it seems to do it on its own.

Here is the test itself. I run this method in a test method elsewhere in the file by simply calling `super_create_fail`. I'm using a patch request because the user gets created the first time they access the app and has access to public features of the app. This "super create" updates the information in the database for that user by having them provide their name and giving them a password, etc.

```
def super_create_fail
  #super create user
  patch "/api/users/2/super_create", :user => {:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe", :email => "jdoe1@williams.edu", :password => "anothertest", :password_confirmation => "wrongpassword"}, :format => :json
  user = assigns(:user)
  assert_response :success, "no response from database"
  assert_nil user.password_salt, "password_salt should be nil with wrong pw confirmation"
  assert_nil user.password_hash, "password_hash should be nil with wrong pw confirmation"
end
```

This test succeeds but prints the messages shown above which come from the fact that the user in the above method does not have a matching `:password` and `password_confirmation`. This is all the relevant code I can think of but if you can think of anything more that would help feel free to ask.

Comment: That's weird, unless you are explicitly `puts`ing the errors those shouldn't appear. We'll need to see more code.

Comment: Agreed, there's more going on here than we can see.